# How to configure domain name if frontend running on aws amplify and backed running on AWS fargate

Tags: dns, amazon-ecs, aws-amplify

I have a domain name already i.e test.com

I have created a new web application using reactjs and django

I have Setup the `reactjs` application on `AWS amplify` and i got the public aws url.  `front.aws.url.com`

I have Setup the `django` application on `AWS ECS fargate` and i got the public aws url through ALB as `backend.aws.url.com`

Now i want to use my already existing domain name and put these in a new path

eg:

`frontend` will be on `test.com/testing`

and `backend apis` are called at test.com/testing/api/

How can i do this in aws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> frontend will be on test.com/testing
>
> and backend apis are called at test.com/testing/api/

In order to have them both on the same domain name, with different paths, you would have to place a proxy in front of them that handles the mapping of different paths to different servers, and also does path rewriting. In AWS you would have to create a CloudFront distribution, configure the custom domain name, and configure multiple origins.

---

It is generally much easier, and much more flexible, to use multiple subdomains for front-end and back-end, like:

frontend:  `test.com`

backend: `api.test.com`